# Entity Framework - Filter LINQ by ICollection type using TPH

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm have a class, `Main`, that has an `ICollection` of various types (`SubA` and `SubB`, parent class is `Parent`). I need to write a LINQ query that filters based on these subtypes in EF using table-per-hierarchy. TPH doesn't allow querying the `Type` column directly, so I'm trying to figure out a workaround. I have a method on `Parent` to get the type string. LINQ doesn't support this, however.

How can I perform a LINQ query from `Main` to filter on the type of each child (`SubA` and `SubB`), as well as one additional property of the child?

This is the class method to get the type:

```
public virtual string ReturnType()
{
    return GetType().BaseType.Name;
}
```

This is the LINQ query I was attempting, but fails because `ReturnType()` isn't supported in LINQ.

```
// Main query defined elsewhere in function
query = query.Where(main => main.children.All(child =>
                   (child.ReturnType() == "MS" || child.ReturnType() == "TL") &&
                   child.StatusId != 4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
query = query.Where(m => m.StatusId != 4 && (m is SubA || m is SubB));
```

Or trickier with `OfType`:

```
var subQuery = query.Where(m => m.StatusId != 4);
query = subQuery.OfType<SubA>()
                .Cast<Main>()
                .Union(subQuery.OfType<SubB>().Cast<Main>());
```

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot, that's incredibly simple. Thank you so much, I appreciate it!